# Spotfire - Group values in a column

Tags: grouping, spotfire, bin

Below is a column I have. I wanted to group these tasks like, task 1-5 as September, task 3 to 7 as October, task 5-9 as November. How can we do this in Spotfire.

```
Task 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is a case statement...

```
case
   when [Task] = 1 then "September"
   when [Task] = 2 then "September"
   ...
   when [Task] = 6 then "October"
   ...
end as [New Column]
```

Comment: This doesn't work since the task 3 over laps in both September and October

Comment: How would you determine the differences

Comment: @BULB this is the correct approach, however if your tasks overlap you need to modify your question with sample expected results before any answer can be refined.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if I understand your needs, but you can do a data function (R script) to create another column that will keep the information of the group.

---

If you want to do so, create an input and output variable `dt` (the data table of your function).

Add this line to your script.

`dt["NEW_COLUMN"] <- NA`

Then for each line, replace this NA value by the number of the group

Hope it helps !

---

**Note:** you can also create a calculated column with some `If` if you don't have a lot of groups, it would be better because you won't have to run the R script after each data reload.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment on other people posts, that's why I comment here.

Can you have a task that lasts more than 2 months ? It could be a good idea to create a column with the month of the beginning of the task and another for the end of the task.

Comment: I downvoted because this is a pretty complex solution to a pretty simple problem. Spotfire has great R support, however calculated columns are more straightforward and possibly more performant.